# Setting rank based on query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-5.7

I've a table `items` listing different elements with `id`, `popularity` and `rank` columns.

`popularity` column contains an `int` allowing to sort elements by popularity.

I've made a query to sort by popularity and set a rank for each entry:

```
SELECT id,
       @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM items, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

This query works perfectly and give me a result with `id` and `rank` where the `rank` value is as expected and respect order by `popularity`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to set `rank` value for each entry, and I tried it this way:

```
UPDATE items A
JOIN (
       SELECT id,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
       FROM items, 
              (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
       ORDER BY popularity DESC
      ) AS ranks
SET A.rank = ranks.rank 
WHERE A.id = ranks.id
```

A `rank` value is set for each row but doesn't respect the `ORDER BY popularity DESC`. Instead rank value seems to be set by an `id` order (`id` 1 has `rank` 1, `id` 2 has `rank` 2 etc...).

What am I doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GMB I'm using MySQL 5.7.21

Comment: Try to upgrade to version 8 in which you can use window analytic functions, and possible to figure out easily what you want.

Comment: For what you're doing wrong, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it should be.

```
SET @curRank = 0;

UPDATE items
SET rank = (@curRank := @curRank+1)
ORDER BY popularity DESC;
```

I just set the `@curRank` variable in a SET statement before the UPDATE. When you try to combine them, it just makes readers of your code wonder what it means.

You don't need to make them part of the same statement. The session variable will keep its value as long as you execute both statements in the same database session.

There's no need for subqueries or joins. Just use UPDATE ... ORDER BY (although UPDATE with ORDER BY doesn't work in MySQL if you do need to do a JOIN).

Comment: I did not think it could be so easy! Indeed it works perfectly, thank you very much for this much lighter solution (although from a performance point of view I have noticed a difference of only 0.004s between the two queries on a table of 69k lines)

Comment: That's a pretty small table, it's not surprising that any solution will finish quickly. I work on tables with hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: Yes that's why I specified the number of lines, to put the difference in perspective. On much larger tables the difference can obviously be exponential.

Comment: *"(although from a performance point of view I have noticed a difference of only 0.004s between the two queries on a table of 69k lines) "* @Nexnivis that "overhead" of 0.004 seconds is most likely caused by the `SET @curRank = 0;` MySQL needs to parse and execute that statement after all ..  *"On much larger tables the difference can obviously be exponential. "* The update speed is totallty depended on your hard disk performance..

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has suprising behaviors when dealing with variables and ordering.

One thing that you *could try* is order earlier, by moving the `ORDER BY` on `items` to a a subquery, as follows:

```
UPDATE items A
JOIN (
       SELECT id,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
       FROM 
            (SELECT id FROM items ORDER BY popularity DESC) items,
            (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
      ) AS ranks
SET A.rank = ranks.rank 
WHERE A.id = ranks.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7TPkrbYK3sTZpFf8ZCSAvw/0)**:

Data:

```
| id  | popularity | rank |
| --- | ---------- | ---- |
| 1   | 1          | 1    |
| 2   | 2          | 2    |
| 3   | 3          | 3    |
| 4   | 4          | 4    |
| 5   | 5          | 5    |
```

After update:

```
| id  | popularity | rank |
| --- | ---------- | ---- |
| 1   | 1          | 5    |
| 2   | 2          | 4    |
| 3   | 3          | 3    |
| 4   | 4          | 2    |
| 5   | 5          | 1    |
```

Comment: Amazing! Works like a charm :D Thank you very much I didn't thought doing it this way. I'll mark your answer as solution as soon as I can.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the solution by @BillKarwin: it is simpler and might *just work*.